# How to handle dropdown list but does not show options list in HTML?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, dropdown

I am trying to get all the options of the dropdown list as below:
But I the options list is not shown as in common dropdown list. The selected option is displayed as an inputted value.
Is there any way to get all the options in this case??

```
<div class="oxd-select-text oxd-select-text--active" data-v-67d2aedf="" data-v-13cf171c=""><div class="oxd-select-text-input" tabindex="0" data-v-67d2aedf="">Admin</div><div class="oxd-select-text--after" data-v-67d2aedf=""><i class="oxd-icon bi-caret-down-fill oxd-select-text--arrow" data-v-bddebfba="" data-v-67d2aedf=""></i></div></div>
```

[image]

I can not get the xpath of the options because it's dynamic

Comment: Are you allowed to share the URL in public? if yes, please share the URL of the application.

Comment: Which element are you pointing towards, to get the dropdown?